# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed. Loading from relative path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, webpack-dev-server

I'm using React+Webpack and I have my output path in my config file setup. I see the files in that path but in the browser, I'm seeing it try to look for it in the relative path.
Here is the Webpack config:

```
{
        entry: "./App.jsx",
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/js/InfoCards/ContactListPage"),
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/js/InfoCards/ContactListPage/dist/"),
            filename: "bundle.js",
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/js/InfoCards/ContactListPage"),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/js/common"),
                    ],
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                    use: ["file-loader"],
                },
            ],
        },
        name: "contactListPageApp",
        watch: true,
        mode: "production",
    },
```

In my ide I see the 4 files being loaded into the `dist` folder but the error I'm getting in the console is this:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:20000/customer/1.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

and this:

```
bootstrap:105 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed.
(error: http://localhost:20000/customer/1.bundle.js)
```

Why is it looking for it in that relative path rather than the path I've specified in the config file? And how can I solve this problem?

Thank you any and all help is appreciated in trying to understand this.